# Angularjs: Select ng-model not working

Tags: angularjs

I'm having an issue with a selection box. When I select the option I can't get the value that I just selected. I read a lot of answers, but none of them seems to work for me. Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<select class="wide" style="width: 96%;height: 100px;" 
    ng-options="element as element.type for element in elements"
    ng-model="selectedType" >                                                                                             
    <option value="">Choose an option</option> 
</select>
<p> {{selectedType}} </p>
```

Controller:

```
elements:[
        {
            desc: "example1",
            article: "OF",
            type: "example1Type"
        },
        {
            desc: "example2",
            article: "P-8955625",
            type: "example2Type"
        }
    ];
$scope.selectedType = "";
```

The `<p> {{selectedType}} </p>` shows nothing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`elements` needs to be set in the controller scope. *e.g.*

```
app.controller('ExCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.elements = [{
    desc: "example1",
    article: "OF",
    type: "example1Type"
  }, {
    desc: "example2",
    article: "P-8955625",
    type: "example2Type"
  }];
});
```

Also, attach the controller to your view. *e.g.*

```
<body ng-controller="ExCtrl">
  <select class="wide"
    ng-options="element.type for element in elements"
    ng-model="selectedType" >                                                                                             
    <option value="">Choose an option</option> 
  </select>
  <p>{{selectedType}} </p>
</body>
```

Et voila!

See the *[repl](https://repl.it/@oluwafemisule/ng1SelectEx)*

Answer (score 2):

The `as` its only for the display value, but for the ng-model present the entire selected item.

so you need wirte:

```
 <p> {{selectedType.type}} </p>
```

https://embed.plnkr.co/bicmN1loBGdcxsWOLv6x/